# Can a service know when the system is about to suspend?

Tags: android, android-service, suspend

I have a service which is using gyros. I find that when the system suspends while the service is running, the sensors remain powered up. I would like the service to know when the system is about to suspend so that it can release the sensors.

I've considered holding a wakelock while reading the gyros (I only need ten seconds), but this is a really low-priority task, and I'd rather just drop the sensors instead.

Is this possible? The closest solution I've found is to catch ACTION_SCREEN_OFF, but that's not really the solution.

Comment: `Service.onDestroy()` is not being called?

Comment: Apparently not. The service isn't exiting; the device is just going to sleep.

Comment: `Service.onDestroy()` is called when the service is killed/exited. Services are not paused/stopped when the screen goes off or locked. You are on right track with `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`